# Eliminating coupling and global state in the "Game" singleton

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, singleton, pygame

I'm working on a game (writing my own physics engine), and trying to follow good design in writing it.  Recently, I've been running into many hard-to-find bugs, and in order to catch these bugs easier, I've been trying to write unit-tests.  This has been difficult to do, due to the fact that a lot of my components are tightly coupled, especially to the `game` module.

In my `game` module I export a singleton class instance, which holds the current game state, time, game events, etc.  However, after reading [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) and through researching how to reduce this coupling, I've decided to try and rewrite the class such that it is no longer a singleton.

The idea is to use a `GameState` class, and pass around these objects everywhere, so that unit-tests can create minimal states for tests.  Most functions then just become a function of game state, and return a new game state.  However, **I've run into some design issues**:

My entity objects' position and velocity are python properties that are calculated according to the current time.  This means that I can't simply pass in a `GameState` object without rewriting this as functions (resulting in icky syntax).  Code example:

```
class Entity:
    @property
    def position(self):
        """Interpolate the position from the last known position from that time."""
        # Here, the game class instance is referenced directly, creating coupling.
        dt = game.game_time - self._last_valid_time
        # x_f = x_i + v_i*t + 1/2 at^2
        return self._position + self._velocity * dt + .5 * self._acceleration * dt**2
```

I've done some research on how to resolve this, and ran across [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  Essentially, I could pass a GameState 'getter' object into the initializer of every entity.  All GameState 'getter' objects would simply return the current state.  Example `GameStateGetter` class:

```
class GameStateGetter:
    _CurrentState = None

    def update(self, new_state):
        GameStateGetter._CurrentState = new_state

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # GameState object properties are immutable, so this can't cause issues
        return getattr(GameStateGetter._CurrentState, name)
```

Now for my questions.

- Would using GameState 'getter' objects even be a good idea?

One problem would be the interface for updating the current game state (I have defined an `update` method, but this seems like a strange interface).  Also, given that the problem with global variables is unpredictable program state, this wouldn't really prevent that.

- Is there another way to "inject" the `game` dependency to the `Entity` class's `position` property?

Ideally, I want to keep things simple.  A `GameStateGetter` class sounds very abstract (even if the implementation is simple).  It would be nice if my properties could implicitly pass the current state.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Comment: The more common term is "provider."  (Which keeps you from confusing provider objects with getter methods.)  And yes, using them is a good idea.  Dependency injection is like violence:  if it doesn't work, you're probably not using enough of it.

Comment: @RobertRossney Thanks!  My newfound understanding of Dependency Injection now connects with some code I've seen before with classes named '<Name>Provider'.  Perhaps with some additional information, this could be accepted as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting a `GameStateProvider` into the `Entity` constructor is a pretty simple place to start, and it leaves you with something that can be refactored as your logic becomes more complex.

There's no need to update each`Entity` with a new state when the state changes, though.  If the provider's an object, it's mutable by default.  (Why would you want something that changes all the time, the game state, to be immutable, anyway?)  You can change the `current_time` attribute on the provider and then any time something gets `position` it will contain the correct value.

The pattern looks like this:

```
class Entity(object):

   def __init__(self, game_state_provider):
      self.provider = game_state_provider

   @property
   def position(self):
      # lazily evaluate position as a function of the current time
      if self._last_valid_time == self.provider.current_time:
         return self._position
      self._last_valid_time = self.provider.current_time
      self._position = // insert physics here
      return self._position
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure about the first question, but it does sound a bit far fetched.

As to the second question: When unit-testing, you could import the *game* module first, then monkey-patch the global game state to be the mock game state. From now on, all functions/properties will be using the mock game state. I would do it in the *setUp* method of  the unit-test framework of choice.

Edit:

Why not make module-level attribute "GameState" in your *game* module. You could access that from anywhere. If you want copies of GameState, define a *clone* (or __deepcopy__) method on it.

Comment: I suppose that could work for the unit-testing, thanks!  As for my second question -- I was actually referring to allowing the `Entity` position property to get access to the `game` dependency.  I will edit to make this clearer.